# Don't know how to call classes in python using if function

Tags: python, function, class, if-statement

So I am making a program in which it reads a .txt file and runs different classes; I made it so it opens the file and stores the text in a decision string, Using if decision == "wincode" or "lostcode" I want it to run a specific class like:

```
class wonToss():
    
    wininput = input("Do you want to choose: ")

    def outChoice():
        print("no error")

    
    def inChoice():
        print("No error")
        


    if wininput == "Indoor":
        inChoice()
    elif wininput == "Outdoor":
        outChoice()
```

I put the "No error" for testing to see if it works

```
class lostToss():

    def botChoose():
        print("Bot is choosing between Indoor and Outdoor.")
        print(".")
        time.sleep(0.25)
        print("..")
        time.sleep(0.25)
        print("...")
        time.sleep(0.25)
        print("")
        choices = ['Indoor', 'Outdoor']
        botting = random.choice(choices)
        print(f"And the bot chose: {botting}")
        time.sleep(2)

    botChoose()
```

And this is the second class. So now, I want it to check the code and class the specific class.

This is the check code:

```
f=open("TossDecision.ch", "r")

if f.mode == 'r':
    decision = f.read()

if decision == "jhe78r2dbgv67t2yhdb7vgr":
    print("")
    wonToss()

elif decision == "jhe78rnxshwdn7wgh89u3cn":
    print("")
    lostToss()

else:
    print("Toss Decision changed! Re-run the PlayGame file.")
    exit()
```

But the problem is,
When I run the program it just shows:

```
Do you want to choose (Indoor) or (Outdoor)?: Indoor
Bot is choosing between Indoor and Outdoor.
.
..
...
```

And the bot chose: Indoor

It calls both the classes. Currently its set to loss. It still calls `wonToss()` Can anyone help fix this

Comment: The way you use classes is an anti-pattern. A class is intended to be a type for objects, and should mainly be used to create instances of itself... I could not really understand what you were trying to do, but I can tell you that you are on the wrong path...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but you are using classes totally wrong.

Please read on Object-oriented programming.

1. A class is a **blueprint** for an object.
2. In most times, you **instantiate** an object of the class, and work with it. Like this:

> ```
> class Mything:
>     def InChoice(self):
>         print("No errror indoors")
>     def OutChoice(self):
>         print("No error outdoors")
>     def ask_choice(self):
>         wininput = input("Do you want to choose: ")
>         if wininput == "Indoor":
>            self.InChoice()
>         elif wininput == "Outdoor":
>            self.OutChoice()
> ```

Then in your program you do:

```
  choice_object=Mything()
  choice_object.ask_choice()
```